# how to append a list of data to form in jQuery, and fecth it in controller

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

```
var form = $('#myForm');
form.submit(function() {
  var selectedItems = $('myTable').data("selectedItems");
  form.append('selectedItems');
  var data = form.serialize();
  var url = "/myController/formData";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
  });
});
```

I'm trying to fetch it in Controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myController")
public class myController
{
  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value="/formData", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void formData(final Model mymodel)
  {
    //some actions
  }
}
```

I need to know how can I fetch list from the returned data from jQuery.

Comment: Your question isn't clear; are you trying to get the data JS sends in the Controller, or the response from the request in JS?

Comment: Hi I'm getting my form data in mymodel object but since the List is appended in form through js I'm not able to fetch the data of the List or to be honest I dont really know how can I fetch List in my controller

Comment: P.S the form is binded to model but the Data from List isnt so i need to somehow get it in my Controller. I tried using @RequestParam